# Update textarea with a value from a selectbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, how do I to set value from a select to a textarea field when a user selects.

```
<div class="controls" ng-controller = "TemplateCtrl">
    <select ng-model = "template" ng-options="template.fname for template in templates">    
        <option value="">-- choose template --</option>                
    </select>
    Currently selected: {{ {selected_template:template} }}   
</div>
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Please post `templates` model. Nothing to do with this example

Comment: Hi , this is what my template model looks like. $scope.template = {'msgtext':'hello there'};

Comment: yes, but what about `templates` array?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
           <div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
                     <select ng-model = "template" ng-options="template.fname as template.fname for template in templates">    
                        <option value="">-- choose template --</option>                
                     </select>
                  Currently selected: {{ template }}
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.templates =[
                   {'fname':'hello there1'},
                   {'fname':'hello there2'},
                   {'fname':'hello there3'}
                  ];
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/870/)